# Speech Recognition Engine Breaking Down a Command

Tags: c#, command, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech

I am writing a WPF application that needs to recognize spoken commands from the user. Being new to the Speech Recognition Engine, I am unsure of how I can accomplish what I need to do the best way possible. The flow of the application would be as follows:

- User speaks a keyword to 'awaken' the app (ex Amazon Echo requiring the user to say 'Alexa')
- User speaks the command for the app to perform (ex "Play 'some song by some artist'")

My issue is that I am unsure what to do with my program after the keyword is recognized. If I were to play the song the user says after the keyword is spoken, would I need to start a new speech recognizer? This is some psuedo code of what I am doing:

```
    private SpeechRecognitionEngine _listen;

    public frmHome()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetupListen();
    }

    private void SetupListen()
    {
        ResetListener();
    }

    private void ResetListener()
    {
        _listen = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        Choices exChoices = new Choices();

        exChoices.Add(new String[] { "keyword" });

        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Append(exChoices);

        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);

        _listen.LoadGrammar(g);
        _listen.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sr_speechRecognized);
        _listen.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        _listen.RecognizeAsync();
    }

    private void sr_speechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Text.Equals("keyword"))
        {
            //start listening for the command
        }

        ResetListener();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate grammar for your start/stop keywords, and have a flag variable which is set to true when the start command is spoken.

Then in your `SpeechRecognized` handler, you can check the flag and then go on to search the recognized text for the command text.

If you are looking for a small keyword, such as Alexa, you could simply search the recognized text for the keyword before handling the uttered command. [Searching the contents of a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-search-strings-using-string-methods).

I hope this article helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn857362.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `_listen.RecognizeAsync();` with `_listen.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple));`

Now you are able to give multiple commands.